# How to include an IF statement within JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm a newbie to react js and redux technologies and I'm trying to include an IF statement into JSX in order to display a fontAwesome icon only if my state is not set to 'add'..
And the following is my code...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RegionList from "./RegionList";
import RegionForm from "./RegionForm";
import { Row, Col, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./regionManagement.scss";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { regionActions } from "./ducks/index";
import { reset } from "redux-form";
import { faPlusCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const regionStates = {
  add: {
    title: "Add New Region",
    button: "Add New Region",
    selectedRegion: null,
    mode: "add",
    fieldDisabled: false

  },

  view: data => {
    return {
      title: "View Region",
      button: "Edit Region",
      selectedRegion: data,
      mode: "view",
      fieldDisabled: true
     };
  },

  edit: data => {
    return {
      title: "Edit Region",
      button: "Update Region",
      selectedRegion: data,
      mode: "edit",
      fieldDisabled: false

    };
  }
};

class Region extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = regionStates.add;
   }

  viewForm = data => {
    this.setState(regionStates.view(data));
  };

  editForm = data => {
    this.setState(regionStates.edit(data));
  };

  addForm = () => {
    this.setState(regionStates.add);
  };

  addRegion = event => {
    this.props.addRegion(event);
  };

  editRegion = event => {
    this.props.editRegion(this.state.selectedRegion);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getRegion();
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    var selectedRegion;
    if (this.state.mode != "add") {
      selectedRegion = this.state.selectedRegion; // CONSISTS OF the edited name, code and description
      selectedRegion.name = event.regionName;
      selectedRegion.code = event.code;
      selectedRegion.description = event.description;
    }
    let operation;
    switch (this.state.mode) {
      case "view":
        operation = this.editForm(selectedRegion);
        break;

      case "add":
        operation = this.addRegion(event);
        break;

      case "edit":
        operation = this.editRegion(selectedRegion);
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Container>
          <Row className="space"></Row>

          <Row>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <h3 className="space2">
                Region
                 {this.state != regionStates.add ? (
                <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
                </a>
                  )}
              </h3>

              <RegionForm
                title={this.state.title}
                button={this.state.button}
                selectedRegion={this.state.selectedRegion}
                mode={this.state.mode}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                fieldDisabled={this.state.fieldDisabled}
                addForm={this.addForm}
                    />
            </Col>

            <Col sm={8}>
              <RegionList
                viewForm={this.viewForm}
                editForm={this.editForm}
                mode={this.state.mode}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    ...state,
    region: state,
    regions: state.Regions.regions
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, regionActions)(Region));
```

I'm using three modes namely 'view', 'edit', 'add...'Is there any proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use a ternary operator, you're just missing the else statement (i.e. `:`).  That being said, if you don't need an else use the answer from Amit.

Comment: `this.state` is likely to be a predefined state object in react. Are you trying to compare the state object ??

Answer (score 3):

you can use && operator here instead of ternary operator.

```
{this.state != regionStates.add && (
  <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
  </a>
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see 3 approaches for this -:

1. Use `?:` (ternary)

   ```
   {this.state != regionStates.add ? (
     <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
     </a>
   ) : null}
   ```
2. Use `&&`

   ```
   {this.state != regionStates.add && (
      <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
      </a>
   )}
   ```
3. Use function call for this where we can add `if else`

   ```
   {this.renderBody()}

   renderBody = () => {
     if(this.state != regionStates.add) {
       return (
         <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
        </a>
      )
     }

     return null;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

```
{!this.state.regionStates.add && (
  <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState(regionStates.add)}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} color="#007bff" />
  </a>
)}
```

Comment: But there's another problem now...I think it doesn't understand that I'm changing to 'add' mode...because of that once I click plus icon, the its directed to the 'add' mode but yet the previous results (from the 'edit' mode for example) remains and the plus icon still exists...But the plus icon doesn't appear at the very first instance of getting the 'add' form ....Please help me to sort this out...